# C - importing and accessing functions in unmanaged DLLs

Tags: c, dll, static-libraries

Recently, I've become itnerested in importing specific functions from unmanaged DLL files. It appears that most languages have a specific construct for doing this. For example, in C++, to import a specific function from a DLL, you can just do this (taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984739(v=vs.71).aspx):

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices; 
// for DllImportAttribute

namespace SysWin32
{
   [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "MessageBox", CharSet = Unicode)]
   int MessageBox(void* hWnd, wchar_t* lpText, wchar_t* lpCaption, 
                  unsigned int uType);
}

int main( )
{
   SysWin32::MessageBox( 0, L"Hello world!", L"Greetings", 0 );
}
```

Or, for example, in flat assembler, the same import of `MessageBoxW` can be done like this:

```
data import
    library user32,'user32.dll'
    import user32,MessageBox,'MessageBoxW'
end data
```

However, the only way to do this that can possibly be used in pure C that I found is as described here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131313 this involves creating objects, from objects creating .lib's (static libraries), and then linking them, and sounds like a lot of work to do for just importing a function. Is there some shortcut I could possibly use, or will I have to stick with making and using the static libraries?

Comment: Note: the given C++ snippet is actually VC++ because it uses nonstandard extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the method you linked to is "complicated" is because it allows functions to be linked to at compile time, and can be called like any other normal function.

Normally, when linking against DLLs, you actually link against a corresponding LIB library, which contains necessary info for calling the actual DLL functions.

The alternative is to use [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) to manually load the DLL, and then use [`GetProcAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the address of individual functions. You can then call the functions through the returned function pointers (after a proper cast, that is). Here's an example:

```
typedef int WINAPI (*MESSAGEBOX_FUNC)(_In_opt_ HWND hWnd, _In_opt_ LPCTSTR lpText, _In_opt_ LPCTSTR lpCaption, _In_ UINT uType);

...
HMODULE hModule = LoadLibrary(_T("library_name_here.dll"));
MESSAGEBOX_FUNC MessageBox = (MESSAGEBOX_FUNC)GetProcAddress(hModule, "MessageBoxW");
...
MessageBox(0, L"Hello world!", L"Greetings", 0);
```

**NB:** I used the `_T` macro when calling `LoadLibrary`, but because `GetProcAddress` is called on `MessageBoxW`, the call *must* use the `L` prefix.